# Save a corner plot in matplotlib figure

Tags: matplotlib, plot, figure, insets

I have a simple corner plot. Lets just imagine the example from their page (taken from [here](https://corner.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pages/quickstart/)):

```
import corner
import numpy as np

ndim, nsamples = 2, 10000
np.random.seed(42)
samples = np.random.randn(ndim * nsamples).reshape([nsamples, ndim])
figure = corner.corner(samples)
```

Now I want to ask, can I save this full canvas(of 3 plots together) in a single matplotlib figure, so that I may be able to inset this plot in another bigger matplotlib plot.

Additionally I have another question, is there a way to put custom legend/title on corner plots ?

Comment: No, that is not possible (unless you change [this line](https://github.com/dfm/corner.py/blob/6d8fc763ce64fe57ca4ae4495198676a1c1ea35e/corner/corner.py#L230) in the corner source code to allow for taking figures with more axes as input.) Alternatively, you could produce the corner figure, and add other axes later on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is my first post on Stack Overflow, with less than 50 reputation I cannot post this as a comment, hope it is helpful to some extent.

Using this line to save the figure of corner plots:

```
corner.corner.savefig('cornerplot...')
```

Perhaps this is adjustable and can be reloaded as matplotlib subplot objects. Though understanding the source code would certainly be best

Answer (score 1):

The link for the example you posted is broken but you can do the following:

**Before "figure= ..." :**

```
fig, axs = plt.subplots(1,1)
```

**After:**

```
plt.suptitle('CORNER PLOT')
plt.savefig('./figure_awesome.pdf')
plt.show()
plt.close()
```

And Voilà

Answer (score 1):

Since Matplotlib v3.4, you can create subfigures, which `corner` will accept as the *fig* parameter:

```
import corner
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()
fig.set_facecolor("lightblue")
subfig1, subfig2 = fig.subfigures(ncols=2)

ndim, nsamples = 2, 10000
np.random.seed(42)
samples = np.random.randn(ndim * nsamples).reshape([nsamples, ndim])
corner.corner(samples, fig=subfig2)

plt.show()
```

[image]